# Pull messages from Kafka to two destination

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am able to get kafka messages and insert it into hdfs. I would like to be able to pull the same set of messages using a BI tool.

Is there anyway to do that? Do I need to create 2 consumers? or 2 consumer groups?

Kindly advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly then you are probably trying to consume the messages from one single Kafka topic and store them into two different locations. In that case you can go ahead with two separate consumer groups, each consuming from the same topic and dumping into two different place.

The `kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector` takes a `ConsumerConfig` as arguments. You can typically put the `group_id` while populating the `ConsumerConfig` as below

```
    private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("zookeeper.connect", a_zookeeper);
      props.put("group.id", a_groupId);
      ....
      .... 
      return new ConsumerConfig(props);
   }
```

Check the [SimpleCosumer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) example from their wiki page for more details.

If you are familiar with [Apache Storm](https://storm.apache.org/) then you can create a topology having two separate bolts consuming from a [KafkaSpout](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka) and do the required processing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve, one single topic, storing into two different location. May I know how can I create two different consumer groups? Do i set it under the group id in kafka configuration? I am using cloudera, not familiar with Apache Storm.

Comment: consuner group is distinguished by the consujmer group id. Each group should have a different unique id

Comment: May I know where to set the group id? Is it in the conf file?

Comment: I will be using flume & datawatch to consume the messages. Under cloudera kakfa configuration, there is a consumer group id, but it is stated there that's for the mirrormaker. Do I add the other group id there too?